# dishwasher leak from bottom front middle upon start of cycle

Tags: leak, dishwasher

My dishwasher has been leaking some from the bottom of the door in the middle.  There is no gasket there, so that is not the problem.  My air gap was clogged, could that have exascerbated the issue?  I did find out that if I position the sprayer arm so it faces sideways instead of front-to-back the problem is minimal.  Any ideas?  From my internet research it seems that most leaks are in the corners of the door, not in the middle like mine.  And note that it ONLY leaks when the dishwasher starts;  mid-cycle it is fine with no leaks.

2014 Whirlpool WDT710PAYM6

3/16/2019 update.  I took the kickplate off and started the cycle and it is not from underneath the dishwasher -- the water comes out from the front between the door and the dishwasher.  Perhaps my (old) floor settled some and I just need to adjust the front of the dishwasher up?  Or perhaps there is some flange I could add to the front lip of the dishwasher to make it higher?

Comment: My bet would be the incoming fill water valve. If so would also leak when it starts the rinse part of the cycle. Model #?

Comment: Whirlpool Gold Series 2434 Tall Tub BuiltIn Dishwasher StainlessSteel .  I am cleaning it now, putting a cup of vinegar on the top rack and running on hot cycle, and it is much worse than normal.  so I think it could be the incoming HOT fill water valve -- I assume there is a cold and a hot valve?  Now it is leaking on the rinse too.

Comment: oh, and it is not when the water first enters, but when the dishwasher starts to run after the water fills that it leaks.  But just when it first runs (I assume that noise is the spray arm rotating which is why I zeroed in on repositioning the spray arms) -- after that it never leaks.

Comment: Your dishwasher, most as far as I know, only have hot water incoming. If you have a high heat/Pots Pans setting, it heats the water with the heating element in the bottom of the dishwasher. Leak in the center of the door...have you verified it is the door and not some other point? Also, the gasket on the rest of the door could be causing it to leak. Does the door shut completely? Also, model number is different than Series. Model numbers usually start with letters In a Whirlpool it is usually D----- Also, might your washer have a rubber tub flap on the bottom?

Comment: @JeffCates Good points. Definitely only hot water coming in.

Comment: If its not actually the door, but rather center from under the machine, its a pump or hose issue. On the door, make sure all the screws are tight also.

Comment: Oh, and make sure the shut off/float valve is working. When it leaks, open and check the water level. Push and pull gently on the float valve inside the washer to see if it is stuck.

Comment: okay.  I am trying something else right now -- cleaning the filters.  I never had a dishwasher with filters before, so you probably realize where this is going.  I am embarrassed to say it's been almost 5 years.  I took the two filters out.  The plastic one below was a little dirty (sticky wet paper for some reason?).  But the mesh top one was a different story.  The bottom half had stuff that readily washed off, but the top half was totally clogged -- maybe calcium deposits?  Soaking in vinegar now.  Scrubbing with a soft toothbrush.  Will advise if this helps....

Comment: didn't solve the leak.  I am sure that cleaning the gunk out of the air-gap-hose will keep it from spewing water into the sink.  And I am sure that a clean filter will make it clean the dishes better.  But it still leaks from the bottom.  So I will next (tomorrow) check the water fill valve (thank you Manasseh), get on the floor and watch exactly where it leaks and inspect the gasket and that the door is shutting completely and all the screw are tight and the float valve (thank you Jeff).  I will check the tank and my loading too.  Thanks so much all.  I will update tomorrow.

Comment: 2014 Whirlpool WDT710PAYM6.  This is the model number.  I downloaded the users manual and it had nothing pertaining to this issue.  But my china and glasses sparkle now after cleaning the filters.  :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. Your clogged air gap resulted in the tank at the bottom not draining and the excess water level cause a spill over a lip/edge that normally would have prevented the leaking.
2. You are loading something in your racks in such a way as to make it direct a strong stream of water at a point that makes it leak.

Comment: I don't think it's a loading problem as I have tried multiple configurations and nothing helped.  But repositioning the bottom spray arm (to a sideways postion) did help on a normal cycle.  there is never any water in the bottom of the dishwasher -- is there another tank I should check?

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I don't think it's either of these.  I cleaned the rubber pipe as best as I could (since I could only unscrew one end), and ran soapy water through and no more black gunk came out.  I brushed it from the one end too, to make sure.  And there is no more water running into the sink.  That did not affect the leaking at all.  As to loading, I have had the dishwasher for 5 years and it wasn't a problem for the first several years -- I load the same.  It leaks less when I position the lower sprayer arm.  So thx but still searching....

Comment: Whenever you have a visible leak, it is possible (probable) that water has also been leaking below the unit, into the motors, valves, etc., causing corrosion. Before wasting too much time fixing the leak, examine the underworks for damage. You may need to replace the entire unit soon.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers and comments thoroughly I can only think of one thing.

Dishwashers don't really have a *seal* on the bottom of the door. They do often have a drip gutter on either side and a lip on the door that sits in the pan when closed. At full water level, just before starting there is very little space between the top of the water and the top of the pan.

Dishwasher pumps are very strong and when they come on a torrent of water rushes all over but before the water gets suspended out of the pan on the dishes and in the cabinet, you have a violently churning pool of water typically less than half an inch from leaking out.

I'd say your best bet would be to disable the float by propping it up carefully and manually adding in water to a lower level.

If it passes this test the dishwasher is sloping to the front too much or there is a problem with the float.

Comment: thanks!  I can't get the cover off the float to inspect it.  but it rises and falls freely, and spins freely.  I was thinking of adding more "lip" to the door or the dishwasher, just in the middle -- like maybe some duct tape (doesn't that fix everything?).  When I position the bottom spray arm I only get a teaspoon of leak.  I will replace my air gap -- the clamps are so rusted I cannot get the hoses off -- I took the whole assembly off to clean it, but maybe the air gap itself is a little clogged.  So that first, then the lip.  Thanks!